# Protractor only executes the 1st test suite from list

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, protractor

We created this script to run three different test suites , but it only executes the first test suite ( '/TestBed_Scripts/TestBed_1.js) and completely ignores any test files after the first one.

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
suites: {

    TestScript: './TestBed_Scripts/TestBed_1.js',
    TestScript_2: 'FCPS/TestBed_Scripts/TestBed.js',
    TestScript_3: './TestBed_Scripts/TestBed_3.js',
},
helpers: ["../node_modules/jasmine-expect/index.js"],
stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: false,
random: false,
restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    },

};
```

I need to know why the 2nd and third test suites are not being executed? How can we fix this?

Comment: How do you run the tests?

Comment: By executing the command "protractor conf.js" from command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. the filepath for the 2nd test suite   `"TestScript_2: 'FCPS/TestBed_Scripts/TestBed.js',`was not correct and this caused the whole problem. we removed the folder name "FCPS" with a "." and its working fine now.